# Extracting particular tags from an XML and write to a new XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, dom, elementtree

I have an xml like this:

```
<Manuscript>
<model defaultValue="data.TotalResult">
    <object id="data" path="data">
        <condition>
              <comparison compare="and">
                <operand idref="Context1" type="boolean" />
                <operand idref="Context2" type="boolean" />
              </comparison>
        </condition>

    </object>
    <condition>
              <comparison compare="and">
                <operand idref="Context5" type="boolean" />
                <operand idref="Context6" type="boolean" />
              </comparison>
    </condition>
</model>
    <condition>
              <comparison compare="and">
                <operand idref="Context9" type="boolean" />
                <operand idref="Context10" type="boolean" />
              </comparison>
    </condition>

</Manuscript>
```

I want to extract all the tags having name as 'condition', concatenate/append them together and create another xml as:

```
<root>
    <condition>
          <comparison compare="and">
            <operand idref="Context1" type="boolean" />
            <operand idref="Context2" type="boolean" />
          </comparison>
    </condition>
    <condition>
              <comparison compare="and">
                <operand idref="Context5" type="boolean" />
                <operand idref="Context6" type="boolean" />
              </comparison>
    </condition>
    <condition>
              <comparison compare="and">
                <operand idref="Context9" type="boolean" />
                <operand idref="Context10" type="boolean" />
              </comparison>
    </condition>
</root>
```

Any idea how can i accomplish this is Python ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for both parsing and creating the new xml that you want.

Check out the following script and change it as you wish in order to achieve the desired outcome.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

xml_str = """
<Manuscript>
<model defaultValue="data.TotalResult">
    <object id="data" path="data">
        <condition>
              <comparison compare="and">
                <operand idref="Context1" type="boolean" />
                <operand idref="Context2" type="boolean" />
              </comparison>
        </condition>

    </object>
    <condition>
              <comparison compare="and">
                <operand idref="Context5" type="boolean" />
                <operand idref="Context6" type="boolean" />
              </comparison>
    </condition>
</model>
    <condition>
              <comparison compare="and">
                <operand idref="Context9" type="boolean" />
                <operand idref="Context10" type="boolean" />
              </comparison>
    </condition>
</Manuscript>
"""

xml_parsed = Soup(xml_str, 'lxml')
output_xml = Soup("", 'lxml')
output_xml.append(output_xml.new_tag('root'))
for condition in xml_parsed.find_all('condition'):
    output_xml.find('root').append(condition)
print(output_xml.prettify())
```

This will print the following:

```
<root>
 <condition>
  <comparison compare="and">
   <operand idref="Context1" type="boolean">
   </operand>
   <operand idref="Context2" type="boolean">
   </operand>
  </comparison>
 </condition>
 <condition>
  <comparison compare="and">
   <operand idref="Context5" type="boolean">
   </operand>
   <operand idref="Context6" type="boolean">
   </operand>
  </comparison>
 </condition>
 <condition>
  <comparison compare="and">
   <operand idref="Context9" type="boolean">
   </operand>
   <operand idref="Context10" type="boolean">
   </operand>
  </comparison>
 </condition>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Beautiful Soup is a Python library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for pulling data out of HTML and XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree. It commonly saves programmers hours or days of work.